# How to get/set the position of the mouse relative from the application window?

Tags: c#, css-position, cursor-position

I want to be able to get the current location of the mouse pointer, relative from where my form window is. So if I would put my mouse on the top left of the form, it would give me the x and y values of x=0 and y=0, while the form itself might be in the middle of the screen.

Also I want to **set** the position of the mouse.

How can this be done in C#? I'm using a windows forms application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obtain the screen coordinates by using [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx), then convert to window coordinates invoking [PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) on the window.

```
Point p = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

Comment: This worked just fine, though I was hoping there was already a build-in function to do it

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) property