# Get mouse coordinates relative to the active window

Tags: c#

I don't understand how to get the coordinates relative to the active window...
I have a program that keeps on refreshing a label which contains the coorinates of the mouse position, I want the coordinates to be relative to the active window. (ex. i start the program, i click on notepad -> the coordinates shown are relative to the notepad window).
Thank you.

Comment: How about [`Cursor.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) plus [GetForegroundWindow and GetWindowRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878963/getting-active-window-coordinates-and-height-width-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Or, use [`ScreenToClient`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.screentoclient) instead of calculating from `GetWindowRect`

Comment: A combination of PointToScreen and PointToClient will help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728286/how-to-get-set-the-position-of-the-mouse-relative-from-the-application-window?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I reached to solve my problem using Blorgbeared tip...
I get the window position with GetWindowRect, then i get the relative coordinates using Cursor.Position.X - rect.X and Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Y
The coordinates are wrong of about 1/2 pixel but working, ty!

Comment: Could you share the script you had?